# How to build my express backend for production?

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, build

I wrote an Express Server. How can I build it now to deploy it on a WebApp? I don't have any build scripts in the project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have any script in your package.json ? Should be something like "start": "node ."

Comment: Yes, i have start. But i need a build script like in react, or not?

Comment: Nope, you just need to deploy to some host and run "node ." in the folder your app is in. If you deploy to some online host such as heroku, this "node ." command will be launched automatically

Comment: If you're using plain javascript then you dont need a transpiler. So in prod you simply run `node entrypoint.js`

Comment: but what about the dependencies? When I run my node script, it falls over because express is missing. Does node_modules get distributed with my application?